# Lenovo P70-A have ADB connection (Android Studio) but not stoping on any breakpoints

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

Lenovo P70-A
Android 4.4.4
P70-A_S134_150729_16G-ROW

Windows 10
Android Studio v2.0 Preview 4
Lenovo Smart Assistant v1.03
Dev options turned on.
USB bridge is enabled.
Install from unknown sources is enabled.

I successfully connect the phone to the development environment, I can do compiling and runing an application from Android Studio. I can see the logs in LogCat. But when I'm run an app in the debug mode, the debugger is detached. In the console writes:

> Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost: 8600', transport:
>   'socket' Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost: 8600',
>   transport: 'socket'

If I try to connect the debugger to a running process (button "Attach debugger to Android process") an application is closing. In the console I got the same message. In the last LogCat message I get the error message:

> Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0000000a (code = 1), thread 25905
>   (JDWP)

Then I try to use another devices (Sansung, ZTE) I had no debugging problems with the same apps.
Please tell me what to do to properly debug applications.

Thank you.

Comment: I have same problem, in my work I have win7 and everything is ok, but at home on win10 it is not working. If you root your device, you can debug via wifi or you can update win10 to win7 :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I found the answer to your question. I made the replacement of this model. I went to the official store of Lenovo and I tested a different models. Only this model of the phone has a problem. Another models have debug mode with breakpoints. Perhaps it was a bad party of devices or wrong assembly of system.

Comment: Seems like Lenovo are doing something strange to their devices, because I've picked up the same symptoms on a Lenova TAB 2 (A10-70L) There's nothing you can do to get this device to allow the debugger to run an app or attach to an app