# A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0000000a (code=1) when trying to debug Android application

Tags: android, debugging

I am NOT the beginner, but I am strugling with debugging Android application with the P70 Lenovo phone. It has Android 4.4.4. I can run my application from Android studio (2.2.2 - latest version), but I can not debug it. It installs the application successfuly, but when it tries to attach the debugger, Android studio shows

A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0000000a (code=1) error

After few seconds the application on the phone restarts (probably) and runs OK, but is not attached to Android studio, so it does not stop on any breakpoints etc.

More facts:

- Android studio seem to be OK - I can debug the application on another phone
- Application looks OK (was always OK and runs on this phone). Just it can not be debugged.
- even new "Hello world" application can NOT be debugged
- I am not sure, but it seams that this problem started after I agreed with installation of Android update on the phone (it was new phone and it offered system update almost immediatelly. It was probably minor update, approx 20MB and Android version number have not changed after installation)
- I was able to debug the application before the Android update.

Does any of you have any ideas? Please do not recomend reboot phone,reboot PC, etc., it is clear - it did not work :)

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34422769/lenovo-p70-a-have-adb-connection-android-studio-but-not-stoping-on-any-breakpo

Answer (score 2):

The error:

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0000000a (code=1) error
```

means that a crash happened in the native layer (C/C++) code.

Seems like the manufacturer of your phone has introduced a bug to the Android operation system itself. They have already [addressed some issues with a bugfix patch](http://laptopmedia.com/news/lenovo-has-just-launched-an-update-aimed-to-fix-p70s-problems-and-bugs/). If you downloaded all available updates and still have problems I'd suggest contacting the producer himself or install another ROM.

Comment: This helped me. Simply connecting another debugging device did the trick